# What is the undocumented Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_SOFT constant for?

Tags: android

Could this be (intended) to know when the soft keyboard is opened/closed?

```
android.content.res.Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_SOFT
```

Comment: The source and comments are a little confusing/contradictory. According to [this code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java#1980), it means the hardware keyboard is hidden, but a soft keyboard is available, though not necessarily open. But according to [this comment](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/content/res/Configuration.java#361), in that case it should be set to `KEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO`.

Comment: The constant is defined just above that comment [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/content/res/Configuration.java#358).